# Update redundant values across tables in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Say I have users that are spread into these tables:

```
user_notifications (
  user_name 
  user_url
  notification_text
  notification_date
 PRIMARY KEY(user_name, notification_date)
)

user_profiles (
  user_name PRIMARY KEY
  user_url
  birth_date
  ..etc
)
```

Now when users update their info, how is this supposed to work? Update both tables? How to keep track of where the redundant user info is stored if my schema grows and there are 10+ tables? Is there a pattern for that? I can think of a repository pattern in which all these statements go, but am not sure if that's the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Batch Statements](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/4-simple-rules-when-using-the-datastax-drivers-for-cassandra). Batch statements will reduce network round-trips and ensure atomicity.

Example:

```
BEGIN BATCH
  INSERT INTO purchases (user, balance) VALUES ('user1', -8) USING TIMESTAMP 19998889022757000;
  INSERT INTO purchases (user, expense_id, amount, description, paid)
    VALUES ('user1', 1, 8, 'burrito', false);
APPLY BATCH;
```

Comment: So what if i only have 1 primary key available like user_name, and want to also batch update the notification record? How would that work?

Comment: Depends on how your application is structured. In this case you may have to use an inverted index for `user_name` and `notification_date`. The trick to use in cassandra is to design a table around your query rather than a query for your table

Comment: In a query optimized data model (Cassandra's data model) your data is NOT normalized and table design should be geared towards optimizing queries. BATCH statements enable you to upsert multiple partitions and ensure atomicity with any change.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Much appreciated. :)